# How to make JQuery selector to the variable with already applied selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I got the next DOM structure:

```
<div id="one">
  <div class="two">asdasd</div>
  <div class="three">asdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="two">
 iiiiii
</div>
```

I have the next variable:

```
 var selected= $("#one");
```

How to apply the new JQuery selector to the `selected` variable? I expect something like that:

```
var newSelected = $(selected).Select(".two")
```

In variable `newSelected` variable I expect to have :

```
<div class="two">asdasd</div>
```

Any advance? Thx.

Comment: You're looking for [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: God, thanks. Worked out to much ))))

Answer (score 2):

Try the following to select the `.two` within `#one`:

```
var $selected= $("#one").find(".two");
$selected.css("border","1px solid red");
```

(border to demonstrate it is selected)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nTuNF/1/)